# Windows: hide hidden files only in one folder?

Tags: windows, windows-explorer

Is it possible to show hidden/system files in all directories but exclude a few select folders where hidden files (or at least system files) should be kept hidden?

Comment: you'd need some third party app, dunno what. to hide a directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, I don't believe it is.  If you say to show hidden folders in folder options, all of the hidden files will be shown.  You could, however, un-hide the files and folders you want shown, and just keep the system files hidden.

Answer (score 1):

This Command will Hide the folder as if it is a critical OS File when entered into an elevated command prompt. Even if you have hidden folders visible this will not show up:

attrib +s +h “C:\HideThisFolder”

Unhide the folder:

attrib -s -h “c:\HideThisFolder”

Comment: Please read the question again carefully. Your answer does **not** answer the original question.